# Twilio test credentials region permission error

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-javascript

I'm receiving the following error when using test credentials to create an SMS message using the Javascript SDK (v3.54.2):

function call: `await this.twilio.messages.create({...})`

Error Message:
`Error: Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +47********.`

[image: Here is a screenshot form my accounts geographic permissions page which has sending to this country enabled.]

According to the these [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials), the "to" number should be validated as normal. I am using the special test "from" number: +15005550006

With the live credentials, this error does not occur, so I would not expect this error to occur with test credentials... but it does.

Comment: That is odd, and I cannot reproduce this with my own account and test credentials. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this as I don't think this is a programming issue.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for taking a look.